# Can we repackage and break models in multiple classes and packages in Django 1.8?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Since I am a beginner in Django and Python world and I am currently trying to make a real project in it Django but being a java programmer by heart and I generally believe in breaking down application in parts as small as possible.

So I was trying to move **/models.py** file to **/models/myModels.py**, but when I try to do the migrations it was an unsuccessful attempt, so I want to ask whether we could relocate and break default models.py, views.py(like we could break tests files and also put them in specific packages following the naming conventions) or we have to accommodate all code in a single file. Although I firmly believe that we could do this but right now I am unable to find any way to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in `/models`? *"breaking down application in parts as small as possible"* is by no means unique to Java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is that you cannot directly replace:

```
models.py
    class ModelOne(...):
        ...
    class ModelTwo(...):
        ...
```

with:

```
/models
    model_one.py
        class ModelOne(...):
            ...
    model_two.py
        class ModelTwo(...):
            ...
```

as now `from models import ModelOne` will fail, Python doesn't know how to find `ModelOne` within the directory. One fix is to change the imports, to e.g.

```
from models.model_one import ModelOne
```

but this may mean lots of changes throughout your app; it's much easier to use an `__init__.py` to determine what should be importable from `models`, making the directory a *package* that appears to Python to be identical to the single file you had before:

```
/models
    __init__.py
       from model_one import ModelOne
       from model_two import ModelTwo
    model_one.py
        class ModelOne(...):
            ...
    model_two.py
        class ModelTwo(...):
            ...
```

See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages for more information.

Comment: Thank you that works and another reason why it wasn't working was because I was running wrong commands for while making the migrations.

Comment: @HiteshGarg yeah, that won't help!

Comment: It sometimes happens with a beginner.

Comment: @HiteshGarg note that these problems are easier to diagnose if you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full traceback, rather than the not-terribly-helpful *"when I try to do the migrations it was an unsuccessful attempt"*.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will follow this from next time onwards.